# .net core 'Response.Cookies.Append' not working as some station

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core

I am using 'Response.Cookies.Append' for setting the culture as suggested in ASP.NET Core 2.1 docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request).

And it is working perfectly fine at my station. But when my colleague fetches my changes, It is not working.

During debug, I found 'Response.Cookies.Append' didn't add the cookie. Anyone else meets the issue? Any solution?

Comment: Is `Response.Cookies.Append` called if you put a breakpoint? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Yes, it was called, but not added into cookies at the end.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You might have a configured CookiePolicyOption in your Startup.cs in your ConfigureServices-Method.

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
  {
      // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
      options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
      options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
  });
```

If thats the case, you can set the cookie with the `CookieOption.IsEssential = true` like so:

```
var cookieOptions = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions()
    {
      Path = "/", HttpOnly = false, IsEssential = true, //<- there
      Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), 
    };
```

**Update**: If you are using SameSiteMode.None, you also have to set the "Secure" property to true. The cookie will work with https only

Alternativly SameSiteMode.Unspecified does work without https/secure-flag

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks Erik. It works. And also thank you for the explanation. Learned something now.

Comment: I can't have three parameters append extension method. it has only one parameter of keyvaluepair in asp.net core 2.1. Can you please let me know how to add cookie using this method?

Comment: @EngrUmair Not sure what your problem is, but the above solution is working fine for me in Core 2.1, with `Response.Cookies.Append(name, content, options)`.

Comment: This is great thanks @Erik. Works for me using this format - Response?.Cookies.Append(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), IsEssential = true });

Comment: Looking at the docs for CookieOptions IsEssential is described as the following - " 
Indicates if this cookie is essential for the application to function correctly. If true then consent policy checks may be bypassed. The default value is false. " Meaning that the CheckConsentNeeded option within your startup which is set to true will be bypassed.

Comment: I have similar problem like Soledad_Ice - I have in Startup.cs the services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>..., So I tried set cookie option IsEssential = true and next append by Response.Cookies.Append(name, content, options), but it still does not work for me :-(. I am using asp.net core 3.1

Comment: It does not work for me either. I use aspnet core 3.1. OnAppendCookie is not called as well, just in case.

Comment: This does not work for me either. I am also using .NET Core 3.1

Comment: I updated my answer, because people might get into the SameSitePolicy issue @Alexander are you using SameSiteMode.None ?

Comment: @erik-mandke no, Strict: i have IIS site and all web apps within it. But I know now, what's up in my case: AJAX requests do not save cookies.. :(

Answer (score 1):

I use this and it's working for me

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
                     "name", "value",
                     new CookieOptions() { SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax });
```