# How can I set a cookie from an API endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, angular7, asp.net-core-2.1

I am running an Angular 7 frontend that makes requests to a .NET Core 2.1 backend (API).
In the backend there is a controller with an endpoint that loads some data and sends it back to the frontend. After this initial request I want all of the following requests to contain an id.

I tried to do that by appending a cookie to the response containing that id.

```
    [HttpGet("LoadData/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoadSomeDataAndSetCookie(Guid id)
    {       
        var data = await _dataService.Read(id);

        Response.Cookies.Append("myId", id.ToString());

        return Ok(data);
    }
```

When I try to access the cookie from a filter it returns null.

```
    var id = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["myId"];
```

It also does not show up in Chrome.

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52539179/507793

Comment: I found that to but it did not work :/

Comment: You cannot do this. set you cookies in your frontend when you receive the response if you want.

Comment: @itdoesntwork is there no way to set cookies in the backend?

Comment: with your current tools i think it is not. I do not see the reason to do so. In angular, add your cookie when you get your response.

Comment: @itdoesntwork do you know a simple way to set a cookie in angular for a different domain? I have my frontend running on port 4200 and my backend on 5000. But this might change in the future..

Comment: cookies are not permanent.. so you shouldn't care if the domain is going to change or not. Maybe you should describe what you want to achieve and then maybe we could help you more.

Comment: @itdoesntwork I am building a portal that can manage multiple companies, each company has an id. The user can pick what company he is currently editing. I was looking for a way to send the company id in each request after the company data has been loaded (from the backend) so that i don't have to "manually" put it into every request. 
I am now using an http interceptor in angular to set the currently selected company into every http header. This works just fine now :) 
Thank's for your help!

Comment: You are welcome.. that is a very good approach. Maybe you can answer your own question and add your implementation and why you changed your approach. Maybe it can help someone in the future.