# Http cookie from an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API is not saved in an ASP.NET Core 6 Razor pages app

Tags: cors, asp.net-core-6.0

My ASP.NET Core 6 Web API CORS policy is defined as:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowRxEcom", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7230")
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowCredentials();
    });
});
app.UseCors("AllowRxEcom");
```

And I send the cookie like this:

```
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
{
    Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(8),
    HttpOnly = true,
    Secure = true,
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
};

Response.Cookies.Append("AccessToken", accessToken, cookieOptions);
```

My ASP.NET Core 6 Razor pages app cookie configuration is:

```
builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});

app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

I can see the cookie in the response header:

```
{
    StatusCode: 200, 
    ReasonPhrase: 'OK', 
    Version: 1.1, 
    Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, 
    Headers:
    {
        Date: Wed, 04 Oct 2023 02:27:23 GMT
        Server: Kestrel
        Set-Cookie: AccessToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI0MDNmZjhjZi1mODUzLTQ5OTgtOGM3Yy04MjI0Y2Q2OGIwODIiLCJzdWIiOiJhbHNhaWZwaGFybWFjeUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJuYW1laWQiOiJhNGNhMWQiOiJSeEVjb21XZWIifQ.wvo5EjLeUPivMWjfUeNNeOW7OPwfYLgpx-jPNj1AnkU; expires=Wed, 04 Oct 2023 10:27:24 GMT; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
        Transfer-Encoding: chunked
        Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    }
}
```

When I try to access the `AccessToken`, it is null:

```
var accessToken = Request.Cookies["AccessToken"];. // this is always null
```

The cookie is not being set. Are the policies correct?

API url is `https://localhost:7136` and the app url is `https://localhost:7230`.

I have gone through and tried solutions in [ASP.Net Cookies not being saved to the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71343013/asp-net-cookies-not-being-saved-to-the-browser). No luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! I was not saving the cookie:

```
 if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out var cookieValues))
 {
     foreach (var cookieValue in cookieValues)
     {
         Response.Cookies.Append("AccessToken", cookieValue, new CookieOptions
         {
             Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(8),
             HttpOnly = true,
             Secure = true,
             SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
         });
     }
 }
```